# What's the stream equivalent to on.event.remove

Tags: stream, dart

I have some old code I'm updating and the cleaner isn't picking it up.

I succeeded in changing the following:

```
document.on.mouseOut.add(onDocumentMouseOut);
```

to

```
document.onMouseOut.listen(onDocumentMouseOut);
```

but I don't know how to translate this:

```
document.on.mouseOut.remove(onDocumentMouseOut);
```

What's the stream equivalent of remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a reference to the [StreamSubscription](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamSubscription.html) object returned by [listen()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Stream.html#listen), and call the [cancel()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamSubscription.html#cancel) method on it.

```
// Add a handler
var subscription = document.onMouseOut.listen((e) => print('oi'));

// Remove the handler
subscription.cancel();
```